How to remove last parentheses in string with its contents in python using regex?
Say we have a list of files like
(these aren't symlinks btw, I'm just using the arrows to indicate input -> output relationship)
test(1) -> test
test2(1) -> test2
test3(note to self) (6) -> test3(note to self)

edit(not sure why there is a request to close for lack of focus. I'm literally giving you 3 specific test cases here)
We can make no assumptions about the rest of the string outside of the fact that there will be a set of parentheses at the end with something inside. So that means there might be parentheses before the last set of parentheses which should not be touched. only the last parentheses.
How to accomplish this with re python module?

You could probably anchor the pattern with $? Something like \([^)]*\)$ (A literal paren followed by zero or more things that aren't close parens, followed by a close paren and anchored at the end of the string)

Should "foo(1)bar(2)baz" become "foo(1)barbaz"?

yes @Matthias ^^

I'd use a pattern such as:
import re

p = r'^([^\r\n]*)\([^)]*\)([^\r\n]*)$'
s = "test3(note to self)(6) -> test3(note to self) some text"
print(re.sub(p, r'\1\2', s))


Prints
test3(note to self)(6) -> test3 some text

^([^\r\n]*)\([^)]*\)([^\r\n]*)$

^ and $ are the start and end anchors.
([^\r\n]*) group is what you want to keep.
\([^)]*\) we want to discard this.

